# Qusetion about equivalence of limit of a sequence and the point to which it converges

Tags: analysis

I need help with the following question.

Let $(x_n)$ be a sequence of real numbers converging to another real number $x$. Then $(x_n)$ converges to $x$ iff $\lim_{n \to \infty} |x_n - x| = 0$.

Any help appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: "Qusetion about analysis" is neither informative nor correctly spelled. Please give your questions better titles.

Comment: @symplectomorphic done :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Definition.** Let $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ be a sequence of real numbers. We say that the sequence $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ converges to $x\in\mathbb{R}$ and write $x_n\to x$ as $n\to\infty$ if for every $\epsilon>0$ there exists a corresponding $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n$
>   $$
> n\geq N\Rightarrow |x_n-x|<\epsilon
> $$
>
> **Problem.** You are asked to show that
>   $$
> \lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=x\Longleftrightarrow \lim_{n\to\infty}|x_n-x|=0
> $$

First suppose that $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=x$. Then for every $\epsilon>0$ there exists a corresponding $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n$
$$
n\geq N\Rightarrow |x_n-x|<\epsilon
$$
The result follows by noting that
$$
|x_n-x|=||x_n-x|-0|
$$

Now suppose that $\lim_{n\to\infty}|x_n-x|=0$. Then for every $\epsilon>0$ there exists a corresponding $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n$
$$
n\geq N\Rightarrow ||x_n-x|-0|<\epsilon
$$
Again the result follows by noting that $||x_n-x|-0|=|x_n-x|$.

Comment: nice answer. but i want to know where am i wrong.

Comment: @NV-US: I think you are almost on the right track in your proof but somehow you mix the definition of a limit of a sequence with the definition of a limit of a function. In your part 1, you do not prove anything; you start with $x_n\to x$ and conclude that $x_n\to x$. Your conclusion in this part should be $|x_n-x|\to0$. Also using the Archimedeann property is not necessary. The same thing applies in your second part. If you read my answer carefully, you will see that the problem is easy.

Comment: you are very right,but, i think that you mayhave understood my question wrong. i have to prove that xn converges x iff lim xn =x. you never proved the convergence part. In your answer, your "Problem", is different from my question. **Let $(x_n)$ be a sequence of real numbers converging to another real number $x$. Then $(x_n)$ converges to $x$ iff $\lim_{n \to \infty} |x_n - x| = 0$.** correct me if i am wrong. thank u

Comment: @NV-US No, I understood your question correctly but I think you do not understand your question correctly yourself. $x_n$ converges $x$ if and only if $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=x$ are exactly the same thing (two notations for the same thing). I suggest that you have a look at your posted question. Your posted question is exactly what I have written in my answer.

Comment: @NV-US: This is what you posted in your own question: "Let $(x_n)$ be a sequence of real numbers converging to another real number $x$. Then $(x_n)$ converges to $x$ iff $\lim_{n \to \infty} |x_n - x| = 0$."

Comment: oh ok. thank you for explaining :)